# use & symbol in URL Link in .XML

Tags: xml, url

I'm trying to use a URL in xml that includes a & symbol. Any ideas?

```
> <data> <event   start="Nov 25 2012 12:00AM"  end="Dec 31 2012 12:00AM"
> link="getfile.php?table=dbo_MPD_Library_Active
> filename=CompStat-**&**Holiday Presence
> Presentation.pdf**&**field=file key1=2"    title="2012 Holiday
> presents"></event> </data>
```

if i remove the & symbols and leave spaces the url goes to a blank page
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`&` indicates the start of a [character or entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-charref) in XML. If you want an ampersand as data, you must use a character or entity reference to represent it: `&amp;`.